# Masstransit ActiveMq: error message details is empty

Tags: activemq-classic, masstransit

I'm using masstransit + activeMq(MassTransit.ActiveMQ 5.1.3 version). All working as expected instead of error messages. When unexpected exception happens masstransit creates message in error queue. The problem is that the message body is empty. How can I move back the message for further processing after fixing a local issue?

[Please see the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62lfL.png)

[image]

Comment: @Chris Patterson Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with how the message body was accessed when moving the message to the error/skipped queue.

An issue was created: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1154

And it's been resolved.